# Getting 404 on Powershell Query of Cosmos DB

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using this script from the download in this link.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-query-Azure-Cosmos-0a9aa517
However for some reason I am getting a 404 response.

I copy-pasted the url of the db directly. Putting in a fake URL gives me a "could not be resolved" error so I know the location exists.

Based on the Azure CosmosDB API documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/databases 
the $databaseID is user-set and just has to be unique, so I've set it to be the same as the db name and assigned that to the url.

Changing it to be different still gives me the same 404 response message (below).

Edit: Removed original commenting intro for readability

Powershell Script:

```
# add necessary assembly
#
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# generate authorization key
Function Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$verb,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceLink,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$dateTime,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$keyType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$tokenVersion
    )

    $hmacSha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacSha256.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)

    $payLoad = "$($verb.ToLowerInvariant())`n$($resourceType.ToLowerInvariant())`n$resourceLink`n$($dateTime.ToLowerInvariant())`n`n"
    $hashPayLoad = $hmacSha256.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payLoad))
    $signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hashPayLoad);

    [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$keyType&ver=$tokenVersion&sig=$signature")
}

# query
Function Query-CosmosDb
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$EndPoint,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$DataBaseId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$CollectionId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$MasterKey,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Query
    )

    $Verb = "POST"
    $ResourceType = "docs";
    $ResourceLink = "dbs/$DatabaseId/colls/$CollectionId"

    $dateTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")
    $authHeader = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -verb $Verb -resourceLink $ResourceLink -resourceType $ResourceType -key $MasterKey -keyType "master" -tokenVersion "1.0" -dateTime $dateTime
    $queryJson = @{query=$Query} | ConvertTo-Json
    $header = @{authorization=$authHeader;"x-ms-documentdb-isquery"="True";"x-ms-version"="2017-02-22";"x-ms-date"=$dateTime}
    $contentType= "application/json "#  The original said "application/query+json", I tried both
    $queryUri = "$EndPoint$ResourceLink/docs"

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -ContentType $contentType -Uri $queryUri -Headers $header -Body $queryJson

    $result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
}

# fill the target cosmos database endpoint uri, database id, collection id and masterkey

$DatabaseName = "" # name goes here
$MasterKey = "" #key goes here
$CollectionId = "transientUsers"

$DatabaseId = $DatabaseName
$CosmosDBEndPoint = "https://$DatabaseId.documents.azure.com:443/"

# query string
$Query = "SELECT * FROM transientUsers"

# execute
Query-CosmosDb -EndPoint $CosmosDBEndPoint -DataBaseId $DataBaseId -CollectionId $CollectionId -MasterKey $MasterKey -Query $Query
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At D:\querycosmos\PowerShell\QueryCosmosDB.ps1:69 char:12
+ ...   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -ContentType $contentType ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you used `$DatabaseId` in two places:

```
$ResourceLink = "dbs/$DatabaseId/colls/$CollectionId"
```

and

```
$CosmosDBEndPoint = "https://$DatabaseId.documents.azure.com:443/"
```

If `$DatabaseId` refers to your account name, then you would need to change your `$ResourceLink` variable and use the name of the database inside your account containing the collection. If however `$DatabaseId` refers to the database name, then you would need to change `$CosmosDBEndPoint` and use account name there.

Comment: Hi Gaurav Mantri, thanks for your response.
Which account name are you referring to?
I initially thought you meant the azure subscription?

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-documentdb-dotnet#create-a-database-account. By account name I mean `ID` mentioned in the link.

Comment: Thanks, I did add it, somehow still getting that same error with the 404 though.